# Duplicate insert WebSQL

Tags: javascript, json, transactions, web-sql

I've a simple script where I need to loop through some json data and insert this inside my WebSQL db it the row doesn't exist already.

The following code does the trick:

```
var name;
var dbSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
var db;

db = openDatabase("db", "", "Woonscan Database", dbSize, function() {
    console.log('db successfully opened or created');
});

var json = [{"Project":{"id":"10","name":"Promens Care","archive":"0"}}, {"Project":{"id":"12","name":"Woonconcept","archive":"0"}}];

var project_id, name;

db.transaction(function (tx) {

    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS projects');
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, project_id INTEGER, name TEXT)");


    insertRow = function(project_id, name){
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO projects(project_id, name) VALUES (?, ?)", [project_id, name]);
        });
    } 

    for(var i=0;i < json.length;i++) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
        project_id = json[i].Project.id;
        name = json[i].Project.name;
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE project_id = ?", [project_id], function(tx, result){
            console.log(result);
            // console.log(result.rows.item(0)); 
            var len = result.rows.length;
            if(len == 0){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                insertRow(project_id, name);  
            } else{
                console.log('Row exists: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
            }
        });

    }

});
```

In my situation the JSON-object has 2 children (ID:10 and ID:12), the for-loop loops trough it and it will get inserted. However, the second insert contains the values of the first insert. A console.log or a alert will print me the correct values so I'm kinda lost at this point. Did I make a big mistake somewhere..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the second insert contains the values of the first insert.

There are multiple issues here. Mainly You are opening another transaction inside one transaction (insert row being called inside a loop which was already in a transcation).

> I need to loop through some json data and insert this inside my
>   WebSQL db it the row doesn't exist already.

Best way** to deal with this - make it

Use `Insert or Replace` instead of simple `Insert`

```
insertRow = function(project_id, name){
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO projects(project_id, name) VALUES (?, ?)", [project_id, name]);
        });
    }
```

No need to check if the value already exists or not.

Comment: Wow, didn't think about "OR REPLACE". Think you drank some more coffee this morning than I did. Thank you sir.

Comment: @Jordy gallons of tea since morning :)

Comment: Think i should consider swapping then hahaha, have a nice day mate and Ill mark it as the answer in 3 minutes. By the way, do you have any idea why this "loop" created the unexpected insert results? I'm curious what this could've been.